# Tomcat: cannot upload a file correctly 2 times

Tags: java, upload, tomcat5.5

We develop an application which uploads some CSV file.
In order to be sure about our code, the upload has been tested with 2 differents framework : ZK (which manages upload itself) and with classic jsp/Spring REST.

On our local server (windows, tomcat 5.5) all is ok.

On client system (Unix Solaris 10, tomcat 5.5) we have a pb : the first time the file is correctly uploaded, the second time if we change something in data (even if we delete the file) we have the same file as first upload....
It seems a cache or something else disturb the upload.

Any idea ? 
Thank you.

---

[Edit] Additional information

For information, we are on Citrix Metaframe Program Neighborhood (a old version -> v9.0).

For those present at the customer (with or without Citrix), CSV file are uploaded correctly each time.

For us, who are outside, that's not working. 
File A is uploaded, then we modified it (A') then uploaded again...and the result is : file A is deleted (as expected, by programmation) then a new file appear which is the same as A (not A' as expected). 
If we stop Tomcat or even make others http request, the upload works correctly.

We test upload with 2 differents framework : ZK (which manage the upload itself) and Spring MVC (REST). Both are working on our servers with same Tomcat (5.5).

Other thing strange, we have access to an another server (by VPN not Citrix) where we deployed the application on a Tomcat 7 (already installed by the client). All is OK.

Is it possible that is an hardware problem? with a router...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is very difficult to understand your question. With what I understood, you are not able to load any file the second time as the details of the first file are still present in memory/variables. Post your code so that it will be easy.

Try these

1. Start the application, load a file, say A.csv, first time, then stop
   the application
2. Start the application again, and load another file B.csv and see if it is loaded correctly.
3. If steps 1 and 2 work correctly, you can be sure that no one has hard-coded anything in the code.
4. Now, go through your code and see if you have any static variables, being set with the contents of the file.
5. If removing static variables doesn't work, try printing all the variables and narrow down the issue.

Good luck!